# Python Outlier Removing

Tags: pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, outliers

I want **to remove blue dots over the green dots region**.
[image: click image here]

I tried using the residual error method from the blue group, and also the z -Score method from Blue but was unable to remove it.

there is a correlation between x and y.

can anyone please share some ideas or links?

Comment: we can only help if you provide sample data

Comment: but it looks like its clustered.  You could remove the cluster with the highest y value

Answer (score 0):

What if you create a new feature using both X and Y and then set the threshold values?

like:

```
# Make new feature
df['xy'] = df['x'] * df['y']
# Filter
df = df[~(df['xy'] < threshold_val & df['gender'] == 'Male')]
```